# Mesh deforms incorrectly

Tags: armature, bones

When I move this part of the wing on my dragon, it deforms incorrectly, how can I fix please?[image: the left wing is deforming weird]

Also when I move the shoulder bone, the whole body deforms.. When I separated the wings from the body, and tried it. It worked perfectly, what is the problem here? [image: tail image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you rig your dragon?

"manually" you would do weight painting for your bone that parts you want to be deformend if that bone moves.

I did that for your case and i got:

[image]

But your vertex group (i just checked for that special bone) didn't had any weights!?, that's why i asked how you did setup your rig.

and i did this weight painting for this vertex group:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Chris! I didn't know you could weight paint bones since I am a bit new to rigging, but now I understand the problem! :D Thank you very much, friend

Comment: You are welcome. We all started some time ago with zero knowledge...and lot‘s of nice people helped me here a lot!

Comment: Would be nice if you could check my answer as „right“

Comment: Alright! I believe I checked it as right :D Also, other vertex groups seemed to have been weight painted in that same area as that bone which I believe is why it bends like that, not because of the rig but because of the weight paint. I guess I am learning a lot now from your answer :)

Comment: Very good! 